# Hi I was wondering if there was a data type in Python that only allows letters to be inputed and not numbers

Tags: python, string, list

My code is to find what position a word occurs in a list and I need it to not accept numbers as an input.

```
sentence = input("What is your sentence? ")
List1 = sentence.split(' ')
List1 = [item.lower() for item in List1]
word = input("What word do you want to find? ")
word = word.lower()
length = len(List1)

counter = 0

while counter < length:
    if word == List1[counter]:
        print("Word Found In Position ",counter)
        counter += 1
    elif word != List1[counter]:
        counter += 1
    else:
        print("That word is not in the sentence")
```

This is my current code. However, it still accepts numbers.
I know that it is a similar question here: [Asking the user for input until they give a valid response](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23294658/asking-the-user-for-input-until-they-give-a-valid-response)
but I need it to fit with my existing code and I don't know how.

Comment: There is no data type for this - what would be the purpose? You just need to check your input's characters and ensure there are no numbers before proceeding - if there are numbers you can throw an error of some sort, or demand new input.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Filter numbers from the list:

```
List1 = [s for s in List1 if not s.isdigit()]
```

Or raise an error if the length of:

```
[s for s in List1 if s.isdigit()]
```

is greater than 0.

**EDIT**

Added a better number check.

```
def isdigit(s):
    """Better isdigit that handles strings like "-32"."""
    try:
        int(s)
    except ValueError:
        return False
    else:
        return True
```

**ADDED TO YOU CODE**

```
while True:
    sentence = input("What is your sentence? ")
    List1 = sentence.split(' ')
    List1 = [item.lower() for item in List1]

    # Here is the check. It creates a new list with only the strings
    # that are numbers by using list comprehensions.
    #
    # So if the length of the list is greater then 0 it means there
    # are numbers in the list.
    if len([s for s in List1 if isdigit(s)]) > 0:
        print('You sentence contains numbers... retry!')
        continue

    word = input("What word do you want to find? ")
    word = word.lower()
    length = len(List1)

    counter = 0

    while counter < length:
        if word == List1[counter]:
            print("Word Found In Position ",counter)
            counter += 1
        elif word != List1[counter]:
            counter += 1
        else:
            print("That word is not in the sentence")
```

Comment: I'm still not sure how I'd get it to fit into my code.......

Comment: I appreciate your help but I am relatively new to coding and I need to be able to explain my code but I don't know what that actually does or where I'd use it.

Comment: @SidharthChaggar Added the check to you code. I have not tested it, consider it an exercise.

Comment: @SidharthChaggar I tested it to work.

Comment: Ok, I really appreciate that, I have been struggling for ages. Thank You